# Indexing a numpy ndarray with a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, labeling

I am doing a tutorial with the iris dataset. In this process, I have found a piece of code, that I can't make sense of:

**It consists of two ndarrays:**

`iris.target_names` is a numpy ndarray with the labels of the target variable:

```
iris.target_names
>>> array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype='<U10')
```

`clf.predict(test[features])` is a numpy ndarray with the encoded digitis of my predictions:

```
clf.predict(test[features])
>>> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  dtype=int64)
```

**The following code creates a labeled ndarray for my predictions:**

```
iris.target_names[clf.predict(test[features])]
>>> array(['setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 
'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 
'setosa', 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',  
'versicolor', 'versicolor', (...), dtype='<U10')
```

I have thought about it for some time, but I don't understand how this works. Because actually we index a 1-dimensional array with three elements by a 1-dimensional array with more than three elements, right? How can this work?

Would be great if someone could help me with some hints on this topic.

Thanks, Marcus

Comment: You're using the predicted classes to index back into the original labels, so `0,1,2` get translated to the ordinal positions in the `target_names` array to give `'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'`

Comment: Just like position select :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we just ignore the whole machine learning aspect and distill this to a simplified example:

```
In[6]:
# our classes
classes=np.array(['a','b','c'])
# generate some random labels
predict= np.random.randint(0,3,10)
predict
Out[6]: array([0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0])
```

Now if we pass the `predict` array as a mask on `classes` we translate `0,1,2` to the ordinal position in the array:

```
In[7]
classes[predict]
Out[7]: 
array(['a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

There is nothing magical happening here when you see this simple example

You can see it also on a smaller array:

```
In[8]:
classes[[1,0,2]]

Out[8]: 
array(['b', 'a', 'c'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

So in effect the predicted classes are indexing back into the classes by position

The length of the passed array is irrelevant here, all you're doing is providing the indexing values to the array so it creates a new array of the passed in length containing the values at that index:

```
In[9]:
classes[[0,0,0,0]]

Out[9]: 
array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```